# Php reverse array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, web-deployment, php-5.6

I am developing a new website, and I  have a quetion.

**Input array:**

```
Array ( [1319] => ####,[1316] => ###)
```

I have an array and I want to revese him, after the reverse the array would be like this:

**Expected output:**

```
Array ( [1316] => ###,[1319] => ####)
```

but when i'm using `array_reverse` function, it doesnt work for me, I got this array:

```
Array ( [0] => ###,[1] => ####)
```

Why it is happen?

Comment: You can sort it by key with ksort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preserving keys you just pass second parameter to `true` in [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/811189)

```
$array=Array ( 1319 => "####",1316 => "###");
print_r(array_reverse($array,true));
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the best way!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$a = []; //your array

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$values = array_values($arr);

$rv = array_reverse($values);

$newArray = array_combine($keys, $rv);
```

Comment: Thank you! it's working for me. Buy can you explaing me why it doesnt work with only the array_reverse fucntion?

Comment: Glad to help you! @Jack accept the answer when you can to help other guys with your same problem!